# How do I change ruby configuration after install to point do a different path?

Tags: ruby, installation

I am able to run Ruby and use some of the commands.  When I try to install a gem, it gives me a path cannot be found issue.  This is my work laptop that automatically installs a network drive on start (and I will not be allowed to make that stop by IT), but I must disconnect it to run Ruby otherwise I have other issues.  CAnnot VPN.

PC windows 7 - I installed Ruby AFTER disconnecting the network drive.  The path TO ruby is on the local(C:) drive.  Searched H: when connected and there was NO reference to Ruby.

The goal is to be able to run all Ruby functions from my computer as though the network drive (H:) never existed.

It seems that SOME of the ruby functionality does not look to the H: drive, but other, key functionality (gem install) does.

The answer I am leaning to is that there is configuration somewhere that is pointing to the H: drive and that needs to be manually changed.

Any thoughts on where I can do this or where to look?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

RubyGems uses the `GEM_HOME` environment variable as the root directory for installing new gems and `GEM_PATH` for locating existing ones. You can see where they're pointing presently by running `gem env`.

Setting the `GEM_HOME` environment variable to a directory on your C: drive should tell Ruby to install to a place that's still writable, even when your H: drive isn't mapped.

Comment: just to be clear... you think this is a write issue?  So it is actually trying to write the files, but is unable?